# Double bar below UINavigationBar iOS 8

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, interface-builder, uinavigationbar

I have a weird double line showing below my `UINavigationController` bar. It is only showing on this single view controller which is setup the exact same way as others (that don't have the double bar).

Any ideas on what could be causing this?

[image]

Here it is in IB: 
[image]

Here it is running in the simulator: 
[image]

You can see the second gap thing.

Comment: Which controller is at the bottom ? Autolayout used ? Provide some code please

Comment: @Christian Autolayout isn't used and there is no code. Added screen shots

Comment: looks like the cell separator or the table header

Answer (score 0):

I could never figure out what caused this but I simply deleted the view out of IB and recreated it. Doing this solved the problem.